# How can you configure a Beckhoff program to work with a variable amount of physical IO blocks?

Tags: twincat, st

At work we are building an airline machine. It is a machine which holds bicycle frames and it has several stations.

Depending on how much stations there are, the amount of physical IO blocks on the ethercat bus may differ. This may differ per customer.

The amount of stations can be entered via a user interface. So the Beckhoff can calculate how much IO there should be present.... in theory that is.

We would like one single program for this machine which can work if not all IO is present on the ethercat bus. But we do not know how to.

We have found out about Conditional pragmas but that is our last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible to achieve. I've worked in a project where parts of the EtherCAT topology was changing every minute.

You achieve this by a combination of EtherCAT couplers/junctions with identity switches (such as the [EK1101-0010](https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/products/i-o/ethercat-terminals/ek1xxx-bk1xx0-ethercat-coupler/ek1101-0010.html)) and the [Hot Connect](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/ethercatsystem/2469078667.html&id=) functionality of EtherCAT. Depending on your real-time requirements and how fast you want to be able to do the switching of the EtherCAT fieldbus slaves, you might also want to consider [fast hot connect](https://www.pc-control.net/pdf/022012/products/pcc_0212_fast_hot_connect_e.pdf).

Using the above you can change your hardware configuration during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to change the number of IO links while the program is executing. Whenever a change is made to some IO links, you have to reactivate the configuration.

Like you mentioned you can use conditional pragma's in combination with [TcLinkTo attributes](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/3107974923.html&id=) to change IO links.